# Erro convert Hex to Ascii Javascript

Tags: javascript, hex, converters

I receive a binary file (biometric template) and I must convert the hexadecimal caracter to a ASCII caracter. But some hexadecimal caracter the programm do not convert, like hex = 95.

What is wrong? What must I to do for the program convert every ?

bellow the code:

```
var campo = document.getElementById('fileInput');
var hex = campo.toString();
var str = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < prm.length; i += 2)
           str += String.fromCharCode(parseInt(prm.substr(i, 2), 16));
```

Comment: It might have worked.. had only `prm` was defined / related to the code fragment

Comment: Just a nit-pick, JS doesn't implement ASCII, it implements _Unicode_  instead.

Comment: @Teemu ASCII is a subset of Unicode.

Comment: @Barmar Well, that's even a further nit-pick ; ).

Comment: @Teemu Since he's dealing with codes in 2 hex digits, that's just 1 byte, which is the subset of Unicode that's essentially the same as ASCII.

Comment: But how can I solve this problem? Does somebody has an example?

Comment: binary is not the same as hex, hex is just one way of representing binary numbers. You also need UTF8 as ASCII only covers the first 128 chars.

Answer (score 2):

You don't specify what you mean by "do not convert". If you meant decimal 95, there is an ASCII character but it is not printable (NAK). There is no ASCII character for hex 0x95 because ASCII is a 7-bit encoding (0-0x7f). And JavaScript strings are not ASCII, they're UCS-2.

https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-encoding

Comment: But how can I solve this problem? Does somebody has an example?

Comment: I can only help you if you explain what you are expecting to happen, and what is happening differently. Also it would help if you explain whether you mean 95h or 95d.